# phpmyadmin erreur : undefined

Tags: phpmyadmin, undefined

I turn to you because I have a problem with phpmyadmin on my hosting server HostPapa. I asked help for service but are unable to give me the solution. 
Several exchanges by mail brought me nothing but a deep sense of disappointment incompetence of the HostPapa support team.

I connect on the interface of my cpanel and I go to phpMyAdmin to create a table. I then I filled the fields valid. Phpmyadmin replied in a popup: "undefined" (see video)
So I contacted my host that after a brief exchange told me that their directors they come! while dry as if the error was home. I logged from another PC and from a different IP address and still the same error. I galley hang over a week and I did some testing with two other areas also HostPapa is housed and still the same error.
This time I made a video that shows the three domains hosted with them is always the same mistake.
The answer was always dry: we have not invented the phpMyAdmin software'll see.

So that's why I'm coming to you because HostPapa is incompetent!

I found a "solution" to add my databases in my config.inc.php and it works fine, I can connect and create remote tables with no errors. Awesome! I discovered america!
Nevertheless, incompetence and laxity of support makes me crazy.

You have an idea where this error?

creative-trip.com/vids/erreur.wmv

2.
can you tell me if my config.inc.php configuration is correct?

impossible add the code to post so here is txt

creative-trip.com/vids/erreur.txt

```
thanks
```

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version is this? Can you reproduce the problem in http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/?pma_username=root ?

Comment: all information relating to the version so you can see in the video

Comment: then, as I wrote it solely on my host's server that it does not fonctione. On my localhost I have never had such a mistake.

Comment: Ok, this is version 4.0.10.7, an old version that is only supported for security fixes. I don't understand what you mean by your solution: do you mean you defined in your local phpMyAdmin the remote server?

Comment: yes, I have defined my remote servers in my config.inc.php file and it works fine but does not prevent the server HostPapa from creating tables  don't works.it is not to me to do their job but I am very curious to know the origin of this problem.
Have an idea? excuse me I'm using google traduction

Comment: nobody has an idea?
I hope that cater to developers in phpmyadmin I find the solution or at least an explanation.
I do not think there's nobody here to explain the problem
s it please you look at the links to the video and the txt file, thank you